# Cassandra timeuuid in Datastax C# driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, driver, datastax

What C# type is equivalent to the timeuuid in the Datastax Cassandra C# driver?

I am writing a simple user tracking service and want to access the most latest user history. I am trying to create a table equivalent to this create statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_history (
    user_id text,
    event_type text,
    create_date timeuuid,
    item_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, event_type), create_date)
);
```

I have made the following class:

```c#
[AllowFiltering]
[Table("user_history")]
public class UserHistory
{
    [PartitionKey(1)]
    [Column("user_id")]
    public string UserID;

    [PartitionKey(2)]
    [Column("event_type")]
    public string EventType;

    [ClusteringKey(1)]
    [Column("create_date")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Column("item_id")] 
    public string ItemID;
}
```

And I am using this statement to create the table in Cassandra:

```c#
var table = Session.GetTable<UserHistory>();
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

But this gives me the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_history (
  user_id text,
  event_type text,
  create_date timestamp,
  item_id text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, event_type), create_date)
)
```

As you can see, the type of `create_date` is `timestamp` instead of `timeuuid`.

I have tried `Guid` instead of `DateTime`, but that gives me an `uuid` when I am calling `.CreateIfNotExists()`.

Should I use `Guid` instead of `DateTime` for the `CreateDate` and create the table explicit using raw CQL3? I guess this will allow me to read and write `timeuuid` from/to Cassandra (using the `GuidGenerator` found in the FluentCassandra project)?! (Recall: I am using the Datastax driver)

Comment: Are you feeling the love with Cassandra?

Comment: Yes. I love the data model so far. I have changed CreateDate to Guid and created the table using raw CQL instead of table.CreateIfNotExists(). Works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timeuuid is basically a guid and so you should use a guid, [the following code is taken from here: creating-a-time-uuid-guid-in-net and is part of the FluentCassandra project](http://nickberardi.com/creating-a-time-uuid-guid-in-net/)

"Below is all the code you need to generate a Time UUID or Time-Based Guid object in .NET. "

```
public static Guid GenerateTimeBasedGuid(DateTime dateTime)  
{
    long ticks = dateTime.Ticks - GregorianCalendarStart.Ticks;

    byte[] guid = new byte[ByteArraySize];
    byte[] clockSequenceBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt16(Environment.TickCount % Int16.MaxValue));
    byte[] timestamp = BitConverter.GetBytes(ticks);

    // copy node
    Array.Copy(Node, 0, guid, NodeByte, Node.Length);

    // copy clock sequence
    Array.Copy(clockSequenceBytes, 0, guid, GuidClockSequenceByte, clockSequenceBytes.Length);

    // copy timestamp
    Array.Copy(timestamp, 0, guid, 0, timestamp.Length);

    // set the variant
    guid[VariantByte] &= (byte)VariantByteMask;
    guid[VariantByte] |= (byte)VariantByteShift;

    // set the version
    guid[VersionByte] &= (byte)VersionByteMask;
    guid[VersionByte] |= (byte)((int)GuidVersion.TimeBased << VersionByteShift);

    return new Guid(guid);
}
```

Comment: In DataStax there is built-in method for this: Cassandra.TimeUuid.NewId(dateTime)

Comment: Indeed, Luke says so in his answer below... the fact is though that the OP does not specify which version of DataStax they are using, i.e. it is only available in 2.1.3... so if they are using a lower version they can do it manually as per the code above... anyways thanks to all the non commenting down votes people... should i delete this answer marked as the answer?... i.e. the only answer at the time, that helped the questioner?

Comment: @Stas Berkov Cassandra.TimeUuid.NewId(dateTime) is working fine for me. I am using the version [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.5.0 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you solved your problem by creating the table manually.

For people in the future looking for this information, since we don't have a native type in the BCL to represent a TimeUUID like Java, the 2.1.3 version of DataStax .NET Driver introduced a `TimeUuid` struct to help with this scenario.  You can find [the source here](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/TimeUuid.cs).  It's got an implicit conversion to/from `System.Guid` and should work with the LINQ driver's table creation methods if you use it as the return Type for a property.